# How can I tell with javascript if some dom nodes float: left or they go down to a new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-float

I encountered some dom nodes which float: left like the main grid of movies on this page, http://trailers.apple.com/. The main grid is made up of ul li ... with many li items.
Each li item float's left, as the CSS is:

```
#trailers li {
float: left; ...
```

How can I tell from Javascript if a html dom element floats left or it goes down to a new line?

Comment: Not sure you can do this without some calculations...

Comment: If its done with calculations based on x and y then it may be wrong because the movie posters at this website http://trailers.apple.com/ are all part of many li items with float:left. The x varies and the y varies on each row, with both x and y varying then how can we work it out?

Comment: You can calculate the offset from the top in relation to the container accurately, by giving your list items a fixed height. They seem fixed on that Apple page.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this using jQuery by running a function which iterates over all list items and checks a `li`'s top offset value compared to the top offset value of its previous sibling. Here's some jQuery which does this, it skips over the first `li` (as it doesn't have a previous sibling) and sets a red background on each `li` which has a top offset value higher than the top offset value of its previous sibling.

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).is("li:first-child")) {
        if ($(this).offset().top > $(this).prev().offset().top) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79KzR/3)**</kbd> showing how this would work. You would have to run this again after resizing the container. Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79KzR/1)**</kbd> showing what happens when the list items have different heights. It still works unless you define "new line" as "starting at the left side of the container". In that case you could instead check the left offset value.

```
$("li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).offset().left < 100) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

<sub>* 100 is the width of the `li` here, it can be any value lower than the left offset value of the second `li` on the line.</sub>

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79KzR/2/)**</kbd> showing this approach.